# Why does the length of the cursor change when I input in QPlainTextEdit?

Tags: python, cursor, pyqt5, qplaintextedit

The length of the cursor changes when I input a word, and the length becomes the same as the word. How can I set QPlainTextEdit?

```
self.setFont(QFont("Consolas", 10, QFont.Normal))
```

I set the css font family "Consolas", and when I input English words, there is no problem. (I highlight the line number because when I get a screenshot the cursor disappear)

[image: first image]

But when I input Chinese word (this word is higher than English word), the problem comes.

[image: second image]

As you can see, the chinese word sinks (the height of the line became higher and the line sink): it is strange.

[image: third image]

The effect of above picture in Sublime Text is what I want.

Comment: What you mean by "length of cursor"? The selection? The code you posted does not "input a word". Please provide the actual code that shows the problem.

Comment: It would be more helpful for us, if you post a screenshot.

Comment: @ekhumoro I update the question, you can input chinese word(中国) in QPlainTextEdit for a test.

Comment: @qurban I update the question, you can input chinese word(中国) in QPlainTextEdit for a test.

Comment: @WangTao. Sorry, I tried, but I can't understand what you mean. Can you upload your screenshots to an image hosting site and post links?

Comment: @ekhumoro [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/6fhEA.png
  [2]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/JKFbW.png
  [3]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/xq79d.png
I upload the image in stackoverflow.

Comment: @WangTao. Have you tried with different fonts? I don't have Consolas, so I can't test it.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no problem with `QPlainTextEdit`. You are seeing this problem because you are comparing Chinese letters with lower-case English letters:

Have a look:

`中国asdsd`

These English letters look small as compared to Chinese ones, but:

`国中ASDFASD`

In this case they look same sized. Try it in your `QPlainTextEdit`, I tried it, everything is okay :)

Comment: In shackoverflow's div , when you input Chinese letters , the cursor  doesn't change. But in `QPlainTextEdit` the cursor will take some changes , the cursor will sink down, It seems that the height of the lines which include Chinese letters becase lager, How i can control the height of the line in `QPlainTextEdit`, i find no way to  
 do this thing in `QFont` and `QFontMetrice`